# Android ffmpeg library use

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm pretty new to use of ffmpeg library. I used this http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/ to add library to my android studio project. It works well when I run the command `-version`  or `-devices`
However when I try any command with `-i` beginning like for example `-i video.avi` I get the error :

> onFailure : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers                                                                                                    built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)                                                                                                    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>                                                                                                        libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103                                                                                                    libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102                                                                                                     libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100                                                                                                     libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101                                                                                                     libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100                                                                                                     libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100                                                                                                     libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101                                                                                                    libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100                                                                                                   Unrecognized option 'i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/test4.avi'.                                                                                                   Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Am I doing something wrong? ANybody have idea why basic command like "-i" doesnt work?

Comment: Not know why exactly. But I have one clue: The error says `'i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/test4.avi'` is unrecognized. It means ffmpeg takes `'i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/test4.avi'` as a option. It works like calling ffmpeg with this command: `ffmpeg -"not a option"`. This will report `not a option` is unrecognized, while if calling with `ffmpeg -not a option`, ffmpeg will complain `not` is unrecognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your command like this

```
String[] command = new String[]{

                    "-i", "video.avi"};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error I think your your video is already in .avi format. Please try .mp4 format and check there is issue.

Comment: Yes, it is in .avi format. However according to http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs
my command -i test4.avi should just return info about this video file. no convert or anything.
Also i checked for the .mp4 format. Nothing changed

Comment: I used ffmpeg for video compression and that was working finely. I dont get the real cause of your error. Can you please check if there is space between - and i in your code

Comment: FfmpegCMD(new String[]{"-i "+inPath+"}); of course there is space

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but It works like this:

```
 String cmd = "Complete command you want to execute";
String[] myArr = cmd.split(" ");
ffmpeg.execute(myArr, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler(){
 });
```

The problem with this code is that the whole command is being considered as an option, So separate each option and value of each option by using the provided code. Hope it helps someone.